Kotlin Coroutines: Should CPU-intensive tasks be executed on Dispatcher.Default or Dispatcher.IO
I'm working on a Android project using coroutines and I have a sequence of operations that involve both IO-bound and CPU-bound tasks. Here's what my process looks like:

Fetch data from the network (IO-bound).
Parse the fetched data (CPU-bound).
Save the parsed data to a database (IO-bound).
Retrieve the saved data from the database (IO-bound).

Initially, I planned to execute the entire process inside a withContext(Dispatcher.IO) block. However, I'm uncertain if this is the best approach, particularly for the parsing step, which is CPU-intensive.
Here's a simplified version of my current code:
viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {
        // Step 1: Get data from the network (IO-bound)
        val data = fetchDataFromNetwork()

        // Step 2: Parse the data (CPU-bound)
        val parsedData = parseData(data)

        // Step 3: Save parsed data to the database (IO-bound)
        saveDataToDatabase(parsedData)

        // Step 4: Retrieve data from the database (IO-bound)
        val retrievedData = getDataFromDatabase()

        // Step 5: Use the retrieved data
        useRetrievedData(retrievedData)
    }
} 

I've read that CPU-intensive tasks should be executed on Dispatcher.Default to avoid blocking IO threads, but I'm not entirely sure if it's necessary in this case. My questions are:
What exactly qualifies as a CPU-intensive task in the context of coroutines?
Would parsing data be considered a CPU-intensive task?
Should I move the parsing step to Dispatcher.Default, and if so, what would be the optimal way to structure my coroutine?
My intention was to use to execute a use case under one Dispacter.IO
suspend fun <T : UseCase.RequestValue, R> executeNow(useCase: UseCase<T, R>, values: T): Result<R>
{
    useCase.requestValues = values

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        useCase.run()
    }
}

Now the usecase would be running inside a IO thread, and inside the usecase when the repository got the value from network, should I switch inside the IO thread to an Default thread for parsing the retrieved data to object my model? Or is optimal to do the work in IO thread itself?

Yes, your parseData(data) is actually a CPU-intensive task and probably not something which should be on Dispatchers.IO.
From the CoroutineDispatcher Docs,

The following standard implementations are provided by kotlinx.coroutines as properties on the Dispatchers object:
Dispatchers.Default — is used by all standard builders if no dispatcher or any other ContinuationInterceptor is specified in their context. It uses a common pool of shared background threads. This is an appropriate choice for compute-intensive coroutines that consume CPU resources.
Dispatchers.IO — uses a shared pool of on-demand created threads and is designed for offloading of IO-intensive blocking operations (like file I/O and blocking socket I/O).
Dispatchers.Unconfined — starts coroutine execution in the current call-frame until the first suspension, whereupon the coroutine builder function returns. The coroutine will later resume in whatever thread used by the corresponding suspending function, without confining it to any specific thread or pool. The Unconfined dispatcher should not normally be used in code.
Private thread pools can be created with newSingleThreadContext and newFixedThreadPoolContext.
An arbitrary java.util.concurrent.Executor can be converted to a dispatcher with the asCoroutineDispatcher extension function.

So, your code will look like:
viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {
        // Step 1: Get data from the network (IO-bound)
        val data = fetchDataFromNetwork()

        // Step 2: Parse the data (CPU-bound)
        val parsedData = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            parseData(data)
        }

        // Step 3: Save parsed data to the database (IO-bound)
        saveDataToDatabase(parsedData)

        // Step 4: Retrieve data from the database (IO-bound)
        val retrievedData = getDataFromDatabase()

        // Step 5: Use the retrieved data
        useRetrievedData(retrievedData)
    }
} 


To add to this: Switching dispatchers should be done where it is actually needed. For the IO dispatcher that will most likely not be the view model or a use case, it will be the underlying repository or datasource. If you use a framework optimized for Kotlin for your network access (like Ktor) and your database (like Room) then switching to the IO dispatcher is already done internally so you do not need to do this in your code. Only if the frameworks are not coroutine-aware you should wrap their blocking functions in a withContext(Dispatcher.IO) and only expose a suspend function.

Are there any reason why parse data should be done in the Default Thread? There are a lot of IO thread right? And for a simple application like mine which won't be using multiple IO calls at the same time do you think it's required to dispatch it Default?
And if I am changing the thread to Default are there anything I should be considering to care of?

@pepperlove

For your 1st question:
Assuming that your parseData function does in-memory data processing and not any IO operations, as per the docs, it is recommended to have it on Default.
For your 2nd question:
There can be multiple IO threads and even if your app is not using multiple of them at a point, it is always good practice to use recommended solution.
For your 3rd question:
There is nothing else required by your side besides using withContext while switching to Default.

